# SELECT or exec result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date function returning today date minus date of birth. How can I select or exec result?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfCalculateAge]
(
@DOB AS DATE,
@EndDate as DATE = '2999-01-01' -- Defaul is today's date (see below) but any date can be used here
)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result as TINYINT

-- IF DEFAULT VALUE (marked as 2999-01-01 as it doesn't accept functions) IS USED THEN USE TODAY'S DATE
IF @EndDate = '2999-01-0'
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
IF @DOB >= @EndDate -- trap errors
SET @Result = 0
ELSE
BEGIN
-- check if the person had its birthday in the specified year and calculate age
IF (MONTH(@EndDate)*100)+DAY(@EndDate) >= (MONTH(@DOB)*100)+DAY(@DOB)
SET @Result = DATEDIFF(Year,@DOB,@EndDate)
ELSE
SET @Result = DATEDIFF(Year,@DOB,@EndDate)-1
END

RETURN @Result

END
```

Comment: If you want the function to get dates, define the input parameters as date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply return it in select

```
DECLARE @dob AS DATE = '19800101'
DECLARE @enddate AS DATE = '20200101'

SELECT [dbo].[udfCalculateAge](@dob, @enddate)
```

You can also use it when selecting from a table to return the value of the function together with other columns:

```
SELECT dob, enddate, [dbo].[udfCalculateAge](dob, enddate)
FROM table1
```

You can also use it in other clauses, e.g. `WHERE`, but this is not recommended for performance reasons.

If you want to use the function with the default parameter, use `default` as the 2nd parameter as you still need to specify all parameters:

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfCalculateAge](@dob, default)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks Szymon. I was stupid. There 2 params in function.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
DECLARE @dob date;
SET @dob = '1980-01-01';
SELECT udfCalculateAge(@dob, NULL);
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'udfCalculateAge' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: You'll probably need to prefix with `dbo`

Comment: Yes, I understood. Anyway, thanks. But with NULL param this return NULL

Comment: I see. Whoever wrote the function should have used `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfCalculateAge]( @dateBirth,default )
```

or

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfCalculateAge]( @dateBirth,@endDate )
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonysuise. I would know about default param. This is cool.

Comment: What if I want select result not only in years but like in 11/02/1956?

Comment: can you give me an exemple with real data ?

Comment: What you mean? I mean function returning not only years but month.

Comment: the function would be much more complicated. there are similar posts on this site to help you. good luck.